# Assembly Load Error WebMarkupMin.Core.WebMarkupMinContext

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

I am getting the following error in my MVC project (running on .Net 4.6.1 framework);

> Could not load type 'WebMarkupMin.Core.WebMarkupMinContext' from
>   assembly 'WebMarkupMin.Core, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'WebMarkupMin.Core.WebMarkupMinContext' from assembly
>   'WebMarkupMin.Core, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b'.

In my references I have version 2.4.0.0 referenced and in my packages .config I have;

```
   <package id="WebMarkupMin.Core" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

In the web.config root I have;

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMarkupMin.Core" publicKeyToken="99472178d266584b" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling through nuget, which has not worked.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will still help anyone
but I encountered the same issue, and solved it by simply following the following steps:

1. Uninstall a WebMarkupMin.Mvc and WebMarkupMin.Web packages.
2. Install a WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc package.

Upgrade a remaining old WebMarkupMin packages to version 2.X.
In application code need to replace all usings of WebMarkupMin.Mvc.ActionFilters namespace to WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc.

which I found on [this page](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/How-to-upgrade-applications-to-version-2.X)